# How to map array of objects which i need to groupby date property in JSON format with react JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Below is the data i have been working on with. How do i access the "display" array of objects with its timestamp and date as properties in react JS?

```
{"display":
{"2019-12-05 07:15:00":{"1. open":"1.1083","2. high":"1.1084","3. low":"1.1081","4. close":"1.1083"},
"2019-12-05 07:10:00":{"1. open":"1.1084","2. high":"1.1084","3. low":"1.1079","4. close":"1.1083"},
"2019-12-05 07:05:00":{"1. open":"1.1082","2. high":"1.1084","3. low":"1.1080","4. close":"1.1084"},
"2019-12-05 07:00:00":{"1. open":"1.1082","2. high":"1.1083","3. low":"1.1079","4. close":"1.1082"},
"2019-12-05 06:55:00":{"1. open":"1.1083","2. high":"1.1084","3. low":"1.1080","4. close":"1.1082"},
"2019-12-05 06:50:00":{"1. open":"1.1081","2. high":"1.1083","3. low":"1.1080","4. close":"1.1083"},
"2019-12-05 06:45:00":{"1. open":"1.1081","2. high":"1.1082","3. low":"1.1079","4. close":"1.1081"},
"2019-12-05 06:40:00":{"1. open":"1.1081","2. high":"1.1082","3. low":"1.1079","4. close":"1.1081"},
"2019-12-05 06:35:00":{"1. open":"1.1082","2. high":"1.1082","3. low":"1.1080","4. close":"1.1081"},
"2019-12-05 06:30:00":{"1. open":"1.1081","2. high":"1.1083","3. low":"1.1080","4. close":"1.1081"}
}}
```

I have a project to perform a calculation on the Open,high,low,close property values. Tried to map the data with map function but it didnt work.

Please give me some idea to proceed with react JS

Comment: _How do i access the "display" array of objects_. It is not array of object. It is an object and you can use bracket notation to access the data. Like `display['2019-12-05 07:15:00']`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your object to required one.

```js
let temp = {
  "display": {
    "2019-12-05 07:15:00": {
      "1. open": "1.1083",
      "2. high": "1.1084",
      "3. low": "1.1081",
      "4. close": "1.1083"
    },
    "2019-12-05 07:10:00": {
      "1. open": "1.1084",
      "2. high": "1.1084",
      "3. low": "1.1079",
      "4. close": "1.1083"
    },
    "2019-12-05 07:05:00": {
      "1. open": "1.1082",
      "2. high": "1.1084",
      "3. low": "1.1080",
      "4. close": "1.1084"
    },
    "2019-12-05 07:00:00": {
      "1. open": "1.1082",
      "2. high": "1.1083",
      "3. low": "1.1079",
      "4. close": "1.1082"
    },
    "2019-12-05 06:55:00": {
      "1. open": "1.1083",
      "2. high": "1.1084",
      "3. low": "1.1080",
      "4. close": "1.1082"
    },
    "2019-12-05 06:50:00": {
      "1. open": "1.1081",
      "2. high": "1.1083",
      "3. low": "1.1080",
      "4. close": "1.1083"
    },
    "2019-12-05 06:45:00": {
      "1. open": "1.1081",
      "2. high": "1.1082",
      "3. low": "1.1079",
      "4. close": "1.1081"
    },
    "2019-12-05 06:40:00": {
      "1. open": "1.1081",
      "2. high": "1.1082",
      "3. low": "1.1079",
      "4. close": "1.1081"
    },
    "2019-12-05 06:35:00": {
      "1. open": "1.1082",
      "2. high": "1.1082",
      "3. low": "1.1080",
      "4. close": "1.1081"
    },
    "2019-12-05 06:30:00": {
      "1. open": "1.1081",
      "2. high": "1.1083",
      "3. low": "1.1080",
      "4. close": "1.1081"
    }
  }
};

let display = temp.display;

let ans = [];

Object.keys(display).forEach((key) => {

  ans.push({
    "date": key.split(" ")[0],
    "timestamp": key.split(" ")[1],
  });

});

console.log(ans);
```